# How do I permanently change permissions for /dev/ttyS0?

Tags: virtualbox, permissions, serial-port

My system is Ubuntu 13.04 and it works fine, but I have installed VirtuaBox to run Windows XP, which is essential for me to run an application that dialogues with an alarm setup by a USB-to-Serial adapter.

VirtualBox uses ttyS0 as a Serial port and the communication can start efficiently only if command `sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyS0` is given to Terminal.

Every time I boot Ubuntu, `ttyS0` permissions return to the default values and I have to run `chmod` every time I boot-up.

My question is: how can I change /dev/ttyS0 file permission permanently? If this is not a good practice, are there other manners to solve the issue?

Answer (score 16):

There's no need to change system file's permissions. The serial devices have the following default permissions:

```
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout ... /dev/ttyS0
```

So all you have to do is add the user to the `dialout` group:

```
sudo adduser $USER dialout
```

Comment: Thanks Eric, your solution worked for me after rebooting! Claudio :)

Comment: reboot is not required, re-login es enough. if you don't want to close your session you can also do `ssh $USER@localhost` (if you have `openssh-server` installed) and use that terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Solution 1: check group of ttyS0 and then assign it to your user,then relogin or su - user

```
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 64 feb 28 18:23 /dev/ttyS0
usermod -aG dialout youruser
su - youruser
```

Solution 2: if you don't like the first solution edit /etc/udev/rules.d/50-tty.rules

```
KERNEL=="tty[A-Z]*[0-9]|pppox[0-9]*|ircomm[0-9]*|noz[0-9]*|rfcomm[0-9]*", GROUP="whateveryouwant"
```

restart udev or reboot and of course before add your user to selected group