# Standard open /dev/ttyS0

Tags: 13.10, serial-port

Every time i reboot my laptop i need to open terminal and type `sudo chmod 777 /dev/ttyS0`to use the serial port.

For configuring Cisco routers I want /dev/ttyS0 to be open when i boot my laptop.

Searched the internet but did not find the answer I am looking for.

Comment: thnx Eric! this helped me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to use the serial port, there's no need to change the filesystem permissions.

You can add yourself to the `dailout` group:

```
sudo adduser $USER dialout
```

(See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/373269/103139))